# Why cant i see the plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I plot the following? Although the code I have written is simple, I cant see the graph.

```
x=['Red','Green','Blue']
y=[0.2,[0.3,0.4],[5.2,6.9]]
```

Here [0.3,0.4] is range of value from 0.3to 0.4 and [5.2,6.9] is range of value going from 5.2 to 6.9.
I want to visualize the range in form of a continous line.
Thanks

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
xTicks = ['Fresh Snow','Moist Fresh Snow','Settled Snow','Firn','Glacial Ice','Pure Ice']
density=[0.1,(0.1,0.2),(0.2,0.4),(0.4,0.83), (0.83,0.917), 0.917]
pl.xticks(x, xTicks)
pl.xticks(range(6), xTicks, rotation=45) #writes strings with 45 degree angle
pl.plot(x,density,'*')
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values in `density` do not always contain a tuple so what is the range of the 0-the element? `0.1` to what exactly? If I understand the task correctly, there should always be an upper and lower limit. Here is an example of how you can plot vertical lines from the lower to the upper value:

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
xTicks = ['Fresh Snow','Moist Fresh Snow','Settled Snow','Firn','Glacial Ice','Pure Ice']
densitys=[(0, 0.1),(0.1,0.2),(0.2,0.4),(0.4,0.83), (0.83,0.917), (0.917, 1)]

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.xticks(range(6), xTicks, rotation=45)
plt.plot(x, densitys, '*')
for idx, density in enumerate(densitys):
    plt.vlines(x[idx], density[0], density[1])
plt.show()
```

This results in the following Plot:

[image]

For Horizontal lines:

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
xTicks = ['Fresh Snow','Moist Fresh Snow','Settled Snow','Firn','Glacial Ice','Pure Ice']
densitys = [0.1 , 0.2, 0.4, 0.83, 0.971]

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.xticks(range(6), xTicks, rotation=45)
plt.plot(x[1:], densitys, '*')
plt.plot(x[:-1], densitys, '*')
for idx in range(1, len(x)):
    plt.hlines(densitys[idx-1], x[idx-1], x[idx])
plt.show()
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

Comment: You will have to watch out when indexing the array in this case I have added a plot for horizontal lines to my awnser

Comment: Thank you. However, the horizontal lines do not represent the range of density values in this case.